# Error in sprintf("%s not found! Interpreting dose as nanomolar concentrations.") in R

Tags: r

I have the problem associated with sprint error in R 3.6.3(using Rstudio terminal tab).
let me know how to solve below error.

-Command used in Rstudio terminal tab-

```
   Rscript AP_simulation.R -d drug1 -x "1-10,15,20,25" --cmaxfile="my_cmax_table.csv" --hergpath="path/to/herg/results/" --hillpath="path/to/hill/results/"-
```

-Error result example-

```
   loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
   [1] compiler_3.6.3 getopt_1.20.3
   Error in sprintf("%s not found! Interpreting dose as nanomolar concentrations.") :

   Calls: print -> sprintf
```

-Rcode that error occurred-

```
  #--- get therapeutic concentration (Cmax)
      if(drug=="control"){
        cmax<-0
      }else{
      if(!file.exists(cmaxfile)){
        cmax<-1
       print(sprintf("%s not found! Interpreting dose as nanomolar concentrations."))
      }else{
      drugtable<-read.csv(cmaxfile)
      cmax<-drugtable[as.character(drugtable$drug)==drug,"therapeutic"] # should be in nanomolar
      if(length(cmax)==0){
       cmax<-1
       print(sprintf("Cmax undefined, interpreting dose as nanomolar concentrations."))
      }else if(length(cmax)==1){
       print(sprintf("Cmax set to %g nM, interpreting dose as multiples of Cmax.",cmax))
      }else{
        stop("Multiple entries for %s therapeutic concentration!",drug)
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: `sprintf("%s not found! Interpreting dose as nanomolar concentrations.")` isn't correct. `%s` is a placeholder you need to pass some text value to replace `%s`. For example, `sprintf("%s not found! Interpreting dose as nanomolar concentrations.", "my_name")`

Answer (score 0):

```
print(sprintf("%s not found! Interpreting dose as nanomolar concentrations."))
```

is missing an argument for `sprintf()`. Since `%s` is an placeholder for an character wich should be printed in this place. Example:

```
for(i in c("One", "Two", "Three")){
  print(sprintf("This is Iteration Number %s", i))
}
```